# Google Forms trigger alert on choice selection

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to trigger an alert dialog when a specific drop-down question is answered **before** the form is is submitted. Is this possible?

Comment: That's not possible using a Google Form since they only support `onFormSubmit(e)` triggers. However, you can deploy a custom form as a GAS Web App, but you'll have to create the form yourself using standard HTML, CSS and Javascript. With a Web app you can have code that invokes server-side GAS functions/methods in response to any changes made to the custom form.

Comment: Really appreciate the comprehensive answer!